# Combinatorics: the amount of poker hands with a certain amount of unique cards

Tags: combinatorics, poker

The particular problem is: how many poker hands (out of ${52 \choose 5}$) result in one pair and three unique cards?

My reasoning goes like this: ${13 \choose 1}$${4 \choose 2}$ gives the amount of pairs (13 values choose 1, 4 suits choose 2 of that suit)

Multiplied by:

${12 \choose 1}$${4 \choose 1}$ (12 remaining values to choose from, 4 suits choose 1)

Multiplied by:

${11 \choose 1}$${4 \choose 1}$ * ${10 \choose 1}$${4 \choose 1}$ by the same logic.

However, the answer is supposed to be:

${13 \choose 1}$${4 \choose 2}$ * ${12 \choose 3}$${4 \choose 1}$${^3}$

and i fail to see why the result should be any different.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: You accidentally counted $A\spadesuit A\heartsuit - 2\spadesuit - 3\spadesuit - 4\spadesuit$ as being different than $A\spadesuit A\heartsuit - 3\spadesuit - 2\spadesuit - 4\spadesuit$ when they should have been considered the same.  As the cards are able to be "mixed up" in your hand and still count as the same hand, you have no way of remembering which number was selected "first" after having picked the pair.  Instead, pick all numbers used for singletons simultaneously (*hence the $\binom{12}{3}$ term in the correct solution*).

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.